# Getting day difference in 2 dates in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which looks like this:

```
datestamp
2020-04-01
2020-04-02
```

I am trying to do two things:

1. Convert datestamp to date format, because right now it's ABC
2. Get difference between datestamp and the end of this year ( 2020-12-31 )

So that I would get a result like this:

```
datestamp      diff
2020-04-01     275
2020-04-02     274
```

What I've tried:

`DATEDIFF(day, datestamp, '2020-12-31 00:00:00.0000000')`

I get:

> DATEDIFF(day, datestamp, '2020-12-31 00:00:00.0000000')

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Where in [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) did you find datediff()

Answer (score 2):

Simply [subtract](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions.html) the values:

```
select datestamp, date '2020-12-31' - datestamp as diff
from the_table;
```

This assumes that `datestamp` is a `date` column.

Comment: At the moment `datestamp` is a `text` column, what would be the easiest way to convert it to date?

Comment: @JonasPalačionis: [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) `cast(datestamp as date)` or `datestamp::date` - but that only works if **all** values can be cast without an error